# Can't change charset in MySQL 5.7 (from latin to utf8)

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL 5.7.8 on my Ubuntu 14.04.

But I can't modify MySQL default charset. I want to change charset to utf8.

I've searched and view many articles on the internet, but every method that I tried don't apply for me.

I already add 'character-set-server=utf8' and 'collation-server=utf8_general_ci' in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. but it's not working...

How can I change my charset of MySQL? Please answer to me!

- Status in MySQL

  ```
  Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
  Server characterset:    latin1
  Db     characterset:    latin1
  Client characterset:    utf8
  Conn.  characterset:    utf8
  UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  Uptime:                 1 min 24 sec
  ```
- show variables like 'c%'

  ```
  | character_set_client     | utf8                       |
  | character_set_connection | utf8                       |
  | character_set_database   | latin1                     |
  | character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
  | character_set_results    | utf8                       |
  | character_set_server     | latin1                     |
  | character_set_system     | utf8                       |
  | character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
  | check_proxy_users        | OFF                        |
  | collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci            |
  | collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci          |
  | collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci          |
  | completion_type          | NO_CHAIN                   |
  | concurrent_insert        | AUTO                       |
  | connect_timeout          | 10                         |
  | core_file                | OFF                        |
  ```
- my.cnf (in /etc/mysql)

  ```
  [mysqld]
  #
  # * Basic Settings
  #
  character-set-server=utf8
  collation-server=utf8_general_ci
  user            = mysql
  pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  port            = 3306
  basedir         = /usr
  datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
  tmpdir          = /tmp
  lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
  skip-external-locking
  character-set-server=utf8
  collation-server=utf8_general_ci
  init_connect=set collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
  init_connect=set names utf8
  character-set-client-handshake=FALSE
  ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Setting UTF-8 `character set` and `collation` for the MySQL server:

`sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Then press <kbd>i</kbd> and add the following:

```
...
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
...
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

Then restart the server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Check your configuration:

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%"; 


+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show variables like "%collation%";


+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

- Setting UTF-8 `character set` and `collation` for the database and tables:

Specify it explicitly when creating the database:

`CREATE DATABASE some_database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Check your configuration:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE DATABASE ... 
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE ...
```